# Permutations with repetition of length different from input vector

Tags: vector, combinations, octave, linear-algebra, algebra

How can I solve the problem of showing all possible combinations of vector

```
x ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

In which I would multiply it by itself.
I want a solution like this:

```
"aa","ab","ac",..."za","zb",.."zz"
```

Which I can index it every element.

I would also like the solultions for the same multiplication where I would get the result for three and four identical x vectors, i.e. the solutions would be:

```
"aaa","aab"..."zzz" and "aaaa","aaab",..."zzzz"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the function `ndgrid()`. Its results depend on the number of output arguments. This is the answer for all sets of 3 with repetition

```
octave> [x y z] = ndgrid ("abcdef");
octave> allcombs = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
```

I'm not printing the results because it's quite long. Playing with the functions `ndgrid()`, `perms()`, and `nchoosek()` will allow tot solve this type of problems very easily.

For n length, use `nthargout()`.

```
octave> cart  = nthargout ([1:n], @ndgrid, "abcdef");
octave> combs = cell2mat (cellfun (@(c) c(:), cart, "UniformOutput", false));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you map the letters to integers (see toascii), you could generate all combinations by adding numbers in base 25 (toascii('z') - toascii('a')). For example, 0 -> 'a', 25 -> 'z', 26 -> 'ba', and so on.

This way you generate all combinations sequentially

Comment: Thanx for answer, but i find some better idea. Here i found some new code, where i working with int, but i can handle that.                  a = 1:4;
b = 1:3;
c = reshape( repmat(a, numel(b), 1), numel(a) * numel(b), 1 );
d = repmat(b(:), length(a), 1);
e = [c d] 
but...if anyone knows, how i modify this code, for use with 3, and 4 vectors?